# Laravel "working with models" & my DB tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have several tables in my database. `Blogs`, `Users`, `Posts`, `Tags` are the main ones. Also I have linking tables: `User_blogs`, `Blog_posts` & `Post_tags`.

My question is how to use Laravel's classes and methods like `belogs_to()`, `has_many()`.
I need someone shed light on it. I've read many articles and documentation, but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1):

Generally laravel is smart enough to detect many-to-many relationships if you set up your tables properly  Both table names should be not pluralized in the intermediate/pivot table so you should have `Users`, `Blogs`, `Posts`, `Tags` as your individual tables and `User_Blog`, `Blog_Post`, `Post_Tag` as your intermediate tables.  In those tables the cols should properly reflect the `tablename_id` (in lowercase) so in `User_Blog` it should have 3 cols `id`, `user_id`, `blog_id` etc and so on for the other columns.

In your models you just need to set up the many-to-many relationships

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
     public function blogs()
     {
         return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Blog');
     }
}
```

And so on for each model.  If changing the structure isn't an option then simply add the table name in the many-to-many relationship like so `return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Blog', 'User_blogs');`

Comment: I'd just like to add in that you will thank yourself later if you go ahead and adopt the standard Laravel ORM table naming convention now. ie: blogs, users, blog_user

Comment: I do not know why but it's asking me for columns: user_blogs.created_at & user_blogs.updated_at. Are those necessary?

Comment: They are expected.  Just put `public static $timestamps = false;` in your model to disable Laravel's built in timestamps.